# Is there a Stack Exchange site where questions regarding building & construction could be asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

As the title already reveals, I have a question regarding building/construction.

More precisely about outside
facade/stucco and which detergents are suitable for cleaning it (since it became a bit dirty over the last 20 years) and which detergents/compounds aren't a good fit because they could be too abrasive/aggressive towards the lime in the plastering (not asking for a specific product-recommendation).

Is there a stack where such a question would be on topic?

Comment: I followed Glorfindels instruction and searched on DIY. Since I couldn't find a similar questions I posted my own here (In case anyone is knowledgable about that topic and could answer my question): https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/228592/which-chemicals-detergents-are-suitable-for-cleaning-my-painted-outside-faccade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question looks similar to [How should I clean my slate and stucco outdoor patio area?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/28661/56858) on [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) (a.k.a. DIY Stack Exchange).

Their [Help Center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does mention that (like many other Stack Exchange sites) they don't do product recommendations, so perhaps you have to reword your question a bit.

Comment: Thx for the hint! Actually I'm not looking for a specific product recommendation but rather an advice  which chemicals/detergents could be too abrasive/aggresive towards the lime in the plastering or the color painted on top of it.